# Abstract class generic-through-constructor inheritance

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, polymorphism, java-8

I'd like to do a model like the following, where a generic abstract class gets the type from the constructor (ala ArrayList())

```
public abstract class AbstractParent<T> {

    protected AbstractParent(T... params){
        //(...)
    }
}

public Child<U,V> extends AbstractParent<????>{
    public Child(U param, V param2){
         super(param, param2);
    }      
}
```

But I canot use '?' or parent's T as '????' type.
I want that `Child<String,String>` to be an `AbstractParent<String>` while
            `Child<String,Integer>` is an  `AbstractParent<? extends Object>`,

...similarly to how `Arrays.asList()` method works: `asList("a","b")` returns a `List<String>` whereas `asList("a",1)` returns a `List<? extends Object>`.

Why is that disallowed or how can I workaround it?

Comment: This is not correct. `Arrays.asList("a", "b")` can also return a `List<Object>`, if you wish. The target type determines that. Similarly, `Arrays.asList("a", 1)` can also return a `List<Serializable>`, if you wish. But since the declaration of a class requires an actual type, a formal declaration of that actual type is required for class declarations.

Comment: But you have to cast them to Object, don't you? At least in Eclipse, placing the cursor over tells you those returning types

Comment: No, you don't need to cast. In Java 8, you can simply write `List<Object> l=Arrays.asList("a", "b");`. What Eclipse's UI will show you, is a different story. We can be happy, if they get the compiler right, one day...

Comment: But a List<String> != List<Object> why does the compiler allow the cast?

Comment: There is no cast. With Java 8, there is no problem in creating a `List<Object>` in the first place when specifying two `String`s as its initial contents. A `List<Object>` can hold two two `String`s. See [Target Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html#target_types)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the parent type to be of some supertype of both U and V, you'll still have to explicitly specify it in `Child`'s generic parameters.  The closest thing you can do would be something like `class Child<X, U extends X, V extends X> extends AbstractParent<X>`.

You cannot automatically infer a common supertype, as you seem to be alluding to `Arrays.asList` doing; you can't do that at the type level.

Comment: I thought of it, but it's not a clean API because then,anybody needs to pass the X type even if it's Object, and the compiler is smarter than us at findind the minimum super common, in more complex architectures of severals nested classes

Comment: @Whimusical that may be true for expressions, but the compiler will not let you express that in the context you want to express it.  This is as good as it will get.